# Google Script Custom Function simple IF statement not working

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Scripts. I have created a custom function script in my Google Sheets spreadsheet. I know the process works because I have see the data being passed to the function and data being returned.

The problem that I have is with the `if` statement. It is not finding "yes" even though there are multiple "yes" 's in the column. They all fail to the else. I even tried it with just the `if` and no else but not seeing any "hello"'s.

So can you help me understand why this `if` would not work? Why return input is returning the sent text but when inside the function it can't seem to qualify it?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
function DOUBLE(input) {


 if (input == "yes") {           
        return "hello";

   } else {

       return input;
  }


}
```

Comment: Ok, does that work in the same way for a range? I think I am misunderstanding how the data is passed. Here is my call from the Google Sheet. The goal is to take the text from colum c and return a score. 

=ARRAYFORMULA(
                 IF(ROW(D:D)=1,"Score",
                                DOUBLE(C:C)
                    )
)

Comment: Your right. It doesn't seem to work with ranges.  I even tried it with a range and no array formula and it still fails.  I'll add the google-spreadsheet tag to your question and someone there will know the answer.  I don't use cell formulas very much.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
function xxDOUBLE(input) 
{
 if (input == "yes") 
 {           
      return "hello";
 } 
 else 
 {
     return input;
 }
}
```

I put it in A1 as `=xxDOUBLE(B1)` and then went to B1 typed in 'yes' and got 'hello' back in A1.  Typed in 'no' and got 'no' back in A1. I changed the name to xxDOUBLE because I wasn't sure if DOUBLE might be a real function because I don't use cell functions much.